# Disposing of parts when removing from container

Tags: c#, mef

I use a CompositionBatch to add a composable part to a container and remove it later by recomposition. All works well, the composition and the recomposition. But my problem is that the underlying object doesn't get disposed. My code looks like this:

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
[Export]
public class NonShared : IDisposable
{
    public NonShared()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor of NonShared");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing NonShared");
    }
}

class Program : IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    [Import(AllowDefault=true, AllowRecomposition=true)]
    private NonShared _nonShared;

    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program.OnImportsSatisfied()");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        new Program().Run();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        var partDefinition = AttributedModelServices.CreatePartDefinition(typeof(NonShared), null);
        var exportingPart = partDefinition.CreatePart();

        var addingBatch = new CompositionBatch();
        addingBatch.AddPart(this);
        addingBatch.AddPart(exportingPart);

        var container = new CompositionContainer();
        container.Compose(addingBatch);

        // Do something.

        var removingBatch = new CompositionBatch();
        removingBatch.RemovePart(exportingPart);

        container.Compose(removingBatch);
    }
}
```

I would like Nonshared.Dispose() to be called, but it isn't. As [Parts Lifetime](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parts%20Lifetime&referringTitle=Guide) at AddPart/RemovePart describes, non-shared parts should be disposed in this situation. Are there some mistakes in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the parts added using the CompositionBatch are handled by the ComposablePartExportProvider (this is an implementation detail) which does not dispose them. Only the CatalogPartExportProvider disposes its exported parts and to use this provider you need to let MEF create the parts.

For more information on this, you can read the first answer by *weshaggard* in [What does ReleaseExport really do?](https://mef.codeplex.com/discussions/228535).

If you work on .NET 4.5 then you could use the **Conventions Model** introduced with MEF2.
Otherwise you can use [TypeCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.typecatalog.aspx)s combined with an [AggregateCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.aggregatecatalog.aspx) to add types to the container, [CompositionContainer.ReleaseExport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer.releaseexport.aspx) to release (and dispose if supported) non-shared parts at will and AggregateCatalog.Catalogs. Remove to remove types from the container.

Here's a sample using a `TypeCatalog`:

```
class Program : IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    [Import(AllowDefault=true, AllowRecomposition=true)]
    private Lazy<NonShared>_nonShared; //Lazy<T> is needed for ReleaseExport to work.

    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program.OnImportsSatisfied()");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        new Program().Run();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        using (var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog ))
        {
            container.ComposeParts(this);
            //Check if the field is injected. It shouldn't be since the 
            //NonShared type is not known to the container yet..
            Console.WriteLine("NonShared field {0}", this._nonShared != null ? "exists" : "does not exist");
            //Add the NonShared type to a type catalog.
            var typeCatalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof(NonShared));
            //Add the TypeCatalog to the AggregateCatalog.
            aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(typeCatalog);
            //Check if the field is injected. This time it should be.
            Console.WriteLine("NonShared field {0}", this._nonShared != null ? "exists" : "does not exist");

            if(this._nonShared != null)
            {
                //Access the lazy object so it gets a value.
                this._nonShared.Value.ToString();
                //Release the part. The Dispose method should be called.
                container.ReleaseExport<NonShared>(this._nonShared);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily test the removal of the whole type catalog with:

```
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Remove(typeCatalog);
```